# How to display a Tikz Flowcharts properly in a RTL Beamer document

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, bidi

```
\documentclass[hyperref=unicode]{beamer}
\usepackage{hologo}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}
\usepackage{beamer-rl}

\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.6cm, auto]
\node [block] (init) {start};
\node [block, left of=init] (Start2) {test};
\node [block, left of=Start2] (Start3) {test2};
\node [block, below of=init] (init3) {process};
\node [block, below of=init3] (End) {end};
\node [block, left of=init3] (End1) {end1};
\node [block, left of=End] (End2) {end2};
\path [line] (init) -- (Start2);
\path [line] (init3) -- (End1);
\path [line] (End) -- (End2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about wrapping the `tikzpicture` in `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}...\end{otherlanguage}`?

Comment: If you need the text inside the nodes in rtl, you could switch back inside the node.

Comment: Works great, thank you @samcarter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a simple workaround you could switch back to `english` for the `tikzpicture`:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[hyperref=unicode]{beamer}
\usepackage{hologo}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}
\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar-DZ, main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont{sf}{Amiri}
\usepackage{beamer-rl}

\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4em,text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em},
 line/.style={draw, -latex'}}
\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2.6cm, auto]
\node [block] (init) {start};
\node [block, left of=init] (Start2) {test};
\node [block, left of=Start2] (Start3) {test2};
\node [block, below of=init] (init3) {process};
\node [block, below of=init3] (End) {end};
\node [block, left of=init3] (End1) {end1};
\node [block, left of=End] (End2) {end2};
\path [line] (init) -- (Start2);
\path [line] (init3) -- (End1);
\path [line] (End) -- (End2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```